# Snipe command returning something I haven't seen before?

Tags: javascript, database, discord.js

so I have a snipe command that works, but after a few uses it returns this? Not sure exactly what's going on, haven't seen it before in any of my bots to my knowledge

`(node:2994) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AbortError: The user aborted a request.`

The scripts look like this, however to my eyes they're just a standard database snipe command -

`messageDelete` event in `index.js` -

```js
client.on('messageDelete', async (message) => {
    db.set(`snipe.content`, message.content);
    db.set(`snipe.authorName`, message.author.tag);
    db.set(`snipe.authorIcon`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }));
});
```

`snipe.js` -

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
    name: 'snipe',
    description: 'snipe the last deleted message',
    execute (client, message, args) {
        let content = db.get(`snipe.content`);
        let authorIcon = db.get(`snipe.authorIcon`);
        let authorName = db.get(`snipe.authorName`);

        const snipeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setAuthor(authorName, authorIcon)
            .setDescription(content)
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(snipeEmbed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(node:2994) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AbortError: The user aborted a request.`
This error is usually triggered when the bot can not connet to discord or database api.

P.S: I suggest add a snipe.channel property to avoid full client sniping.